# C# / ASP.NET Core 6 with AngularJS

Tags: c#, angularjs, web, asp.net-core-6.0

I want to create an ASP.NET Core 6 MVC web app with AngularJS - it this possible?

I tried in Visual Studio 2022 to create such a web app with Angular, but that is a newer version of Angular. Can I change this version to AngularJS, or should I create this project another way?

I need to have AngularJS on frontend side of this project.

Comment: Yes, it's very much possible to do. The default templates don't use AngularJS because [it's a deprecated and unsupported technology](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/version-support-status), and it would be very unwise to use it for a new project at this time. You should be using the new Angular instead. But you don't need to use templates. Just create your AngularJS project, and set up your ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project to serve up its index.html page.

Comment: So i need to create project ASP.NET Core 6 MVC, then download AngularJS and add it to my mvc project yes?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. Though it's hard for me to imagine a scenario where using AngularJS for a new project is the right approach at this point in history. I'd seriously question that requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In theory it works, You need to download related library to your MVC project and add it in your view. Maybe you can refer to this [tutorial](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/302f8f/Asp-Net-mvc-5-with-angularjs-part-1/). But as `StriplingWarrior` said, `AngularJs` is a deprecated and unsupported technology, It is very strange to use such an old front-end framework on a new version of the Net.

Comment: Thank You, I have one more question (maybe it is stupid question) Can I make WEB API in NET7 and frontend with angularJS? What is difference betwen web application net core with angular and web api with frontend angular?

Comment: Hi @Amatour, Do you mean the template `Asp.net Core with angular` in visual studio? It is just a project about `Asp.net Core Web api` as backend and `Angular` as frontend

Comment: Yes thank You. If i add AngularJS like in this instruction, I will be use JavaScrpit. To use Typescript Should I install some more packages yes?

Comment: Sry, I haven't tried it before, But from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38205640/is-it-possible-to-use-typescript-in-an-angularjs-application), you can use typescript in angularJs normally.